# Problema al compilar proyecto en visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Buen día,

Descargue un proyecto de visual studio desde el repositorio, lo abro como administrador y compila la primera vez bien, pero cuando le doy ejecutar o compilar una segunda vez me pide la solucion guardar como, alguna idea?, revise permisos y tiene todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que archivo abres??? el .sln o el csproj?